# Move the scrollview into next page based on the page controller current index

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uipagecontrol

I make the Pagecontroller with scrollview

I write the following code, here automatically scroll the scrollview based on the time interval for every 3sec.

If in case I am trying to scroll the scrollview manually on that time also it will change the scroll based on the time interval.

But I want to move the scroll at the time of manual scrolling based on the page control index.

For example: if present pagecontrol poison is 1, the user manually scrolls that to 4th. According to me, the next scroll position is 5th, but it doesn't move to 5th again it back to 2nd based on the time it is wrong.

```
var slides:[Slide] = [];
var offSet: CGFloat = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slides = createSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func autoScroll() {
    let totalPossibleOffset = CGFloat(slides.count - 1) * self.view.bounds.size.width
    if offSet == totalPossibleOffset {
        offSet = 0 // come back to the first image after the last image
    }
    else {
        offSet += self.view.bounds.size.width
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(self.offSet)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As that timer is running, so after every 3 seconds, it will call the method `autoScroll()`, which performs the scrolling of your `ScrollView`, regardless of your manual scrolling.

First, add delegate to your viewController

```
class YourViewController: UIVieController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
  // EXISTING CODE
}
```

and define a global var for timer. Set it in view, set IBOutlet in your storyBoard.

```
var timer: Timer!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

In your viewDidLoad set it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slides = createSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)

    // Set delegate here.        
    scrollView.delegate = self

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

So, you will have to implement the [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)

1) Implement this delegate method and check if timer `isValid` then `invalidate()` it.
   [Details Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619386-scrollviewwillbegindecelerating) and [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if timer.isValid {
      timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

2) When scrolling ends, you will have to schedule timer again, so that it will start calling `autoScroll` after every 3 secs. [Details Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating)

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I am in learning stage I don't having idea on that logic part then only I ask some idea here.

Comment: Follow my edits. hope it will give you better idea.

Comment: No it don't working if present poison is 1 ,user manually move that to 4th then next moving is 5th , but it don't move to 6th again it back to 2 based on time it is wrong.

Comment: You will have to set the offset value there in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. Check my edits.